# Selenium (Python) does not switch between two select dropdown menus

Tags: python, jquery, selenium, web-scraping, calendar

I'm currently attempting to scrape judgments from this website (https://www.sci.gov.in/judgments) using Selenium, Python and Jupyter Notebook.

I'm currently stuck choosing the date in the jQuery calendar. The following code allows me to change the month:

```
driver.get("https://www.sci.gov.in/judgments")
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="tabbed-nav"]/ul[2]/li[3]/a').click();
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="JBJfrom_date"]').click();
selectByVisibleText = Select(driver.find_element_by_class_name('ui-datepicker-month'));
selectByVisibleText.select_by_visible_text("Jan");
```

Adding the following code should allow me to change the year:

```
selectByVisibleText2 = Select(driver.find_element_by_class_name('ui-datepicker-year'));
selectByVisibleText2.select_by_visible_text("1950");
```

However, the above code doesn't work. I'm only above to either change the dropdown of either the year or the month, but not both of them.

I'm also unable to get Selenium to move to any other part of the screen. Like for example to click the submit button.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="getJBJ"]').click();
```

Why is selenium not able to identify the other dropdown and how do I get it to select both date and month?

Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: Try executing javascript on the page, like `driver.execute_script('document.getElementById("getJCN").click()')` should make get you to click the submit button. And month picker is not visible on the page

Comment: Thank you for your comment! Turns out the above line of code `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="getJBJ"]').click();` does work too. I managed to resolve my solution by upgrading chrome driver to the latest version. My code works and achieves selecting both the month and date now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = r'D:/Automation/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://www.sci.gov.in/judgments")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30) 

judgment_day = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, 'Judgment Date')))
judgment_day.click()

calendar = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'JBJfrom_date')))
calendar.click()

month = Select(driver.find_element_by_class_name('ui-datepicker-month'))
month.select_by_visible_text("Jan")

year = Select(driver.find_element_by_class_name('ui-datepicker-year'))
year.select_by_visible_text("1950")

date = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, '20')))
date.click()

submit_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'getJBJ')))
submit_button.click()
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution! I ran the code above and ran into the same issue of being unable to select the date and month. It was only after I upgraded to the latest version of the chrome driver, did it work. :)

Comment: Yes! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As per the [website](https://www.sci.gov.in/judgments) you have mentioned to select *Month* as **Jan** and *Year* as **1950** you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

  options = Options()
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
  options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\ChromeDriver\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get('https://www.sci.gov.in/judgments')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Judgment Date"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='datepicker hasDatepicker' and @id='JBJfrom_date']"))).click()
  selectByVisibleText = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@class='ui-datepicker-month']"));
  selectByVisibleText.select_by_visible_text("Jan");
  selectByVisibleText2 = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@class='ui-datepicker-year']"));
  selectByVisibleText2.select_by_visible_text("1950");
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: Jan_1950]